# What’s the real name policy?

Tags: user-names

I want to know more about the real name policy and if I can use scrappymatt on google. Facebook uses the real name policy but I’m not sure about google

Comment: I'm afraid it is not clear what you are asking about, and it doesn't look like a security question.